# When to use big O notation and when to use big Theta notation

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I understand that Big O is an upper bound and Big Theta is a tight bound when for example we consider the functions f(n)=O(g(n)) or similarly for Big Theta. 
But how do we know that a particular algorithm will be better represented using the Big theta notation instead of Big O?

For example, the time complexity of selection sort is given as Big Theta of N^2 rather than Big O of N^2, why?

Comment: If a function's tight bound can be expressed as `f(n)` its upper bound can also be expressed as `f(n)`. This is trivial.

Comment: Theta(g(n)) implies O(g(n)) so it simply gives you more information about the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of which is better but rather what do you want to studies.
If you want to study the worst case scenario then you can use the upper bound notation. Keep in mind that the tighter the bound the better, but in some cases it's difficult to calculate the tight bound.
Generally, when people speak about big-O or big-teta they mean the same think so in Selection sort you can also use big-O notation

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above that it is more about what you are trying to study about the algorithm. If you just want the worst case running time, meaning in the worst case the algorithm will run in at least a certain time, then it is best to use Big-O. For example, for selection sort the worst case would be O(n^2). If you want to study the worst and the best case running times, then you would also want to find the Big-Omega. If these are the same (meaning in the best and worst case the algorithm will run in the same amount of time), then you would want to use Big theta to state that this time is a tight bound for the algorithm being studied. This is usually more descriptive because it gives a better outlook on how the algorithm will run with a large dataset. For selection sort, because the best and worst case running time is n^2 (because of the nested loops), the average will be theta(n^2).

Comment: I disagree. worst case can be either big-O, big-Omega, or big-Theta. Also, this is also true for average and best cases.